# Configuring Ports on a Cisco Switch

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-ios, cisco-catalyst, cisco-commands

I am very new to Cisco networking (haven't done any course either). I have been trying to learn a bit of networking myself and had no trouble in doing some of the basic stuff which i needed for my personal work. But i am planning to buy a new Cisco switch(a gigabit switch) and configure it to 2 different networks (1 being an internet and other being a private network for a specific job). I want to configure the ports in such a way that the first few slots for normal internet and the rest for my other network. For example if its a Cisco 2950 48 port switch, the first 1-16 port for my local internet network and the ports from 17-32 for my other network. Can somebody give me a run down on how to achieve this? Sorry for such a long but basic question, i am just trying to save few $$ and learning something new. Any help would be appreciated. Cheers

Comment: I think regarding your practice, the others have spoken. Regarding your switch related issue, I really think you'd require a router in this case if you were planning on implementing this architecture you speak of. Why because, you could use your switch to manage your LANs, but when it comes to going out to the Internet, you're going to need a router to do NATing for you or else you'll be wasting a lot of public IPs (which I doubt you'll get in the first place). Is this a job role you're trying to achieve or just for practice?

Comment: I was trying to do this for learning purpose. Just to get some hands on knowledge on configuring the switch.

Comment: Alright then. If you're trying to get some knowledge on configuring a switch, I suggest you leave out the internet/IP (Layer 3 of the OSI model) aspect of things. I suggest you go with practicing concepts like basic switching within a LAN segment, VLANs, Trunking, STPs and Port Aggregation since these are what are mainly used with Layer 2 devices (switches). You can connect two different networks together using VLANs on a switch (I doubt it's possible with c2950) but I suggest just practicing switching within a local LAN and then practicing concepts of routing which is a whole new ball game.

Comment: There are a lot of books you can buy on these topics. Check Amazon.com, Cisco.com or just browse for books on these topics.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

First have some simulation windows (other OS) machine by using simulators such as Packet Tracer by Cisco or GNS3. Cisco Packet Tracer will give you a head start about Cisco Routers and Cisco Switches. Try to configure them. Look at boot sequence of these network devices.

Comment: Thanks for your response Muneeb. I already bought a second hand switch and put the switch in factory default configuration by deleting all the files in flash (except the ios image) & write erase command. I hope the device is in factory default configuration. Could you tell me the steps for configuring the ports in an actual switch? how can we do it using the CLI ?

Comment: I hope you have console port. Connect Console Cable with Network Device to Computer. Open HyperTerminal, which is included in OS, connect the network device on comm port.
Once you are in user exec mode.

Comment: Once you are in user exec mode.
Switch>
Type 'enable' to go into privilege mode'
Switch#
In this mode, see interfaces by typing "show ip interface brief" command.
This is brief way of seeing interfaces that are up or down.
To configure interfaces, type "configure terminal" to enter into Global Configuration Mode.
You can configure switch interfaces on interfaces configuration mode.

Comment: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2950/software/release/12-1_11_yj4/configuration/guide/lrescg/swint.html#wp1129646

Comment: Once again thanks for your help Muneeb. I have actually got to point of global configuration mode. i am finrding difficulty after that, anyway let me just read through the link you sent me with a clear head.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty straight forward to do, especially starting with a default configuration.

If you wish to create two networks, you will need to use **VLAN's**. These will allow you to segment your network into logical sections.

Once you have created those two VLAN's, you need configure the ports that will reside on those VLAN's. Your VLAN that will connect to the Internet will connect to a port that connects to your ISP router.

To create a VLAN

```
Switch(config)#vlan 2
```

To name the VLAN

```
Switch(config-vlan)#name "Private Network"
```

**Note: VLAN 1 always exists by default and can't be removed. So now you have VLAN 1 and VLAN 2 created**

To assign the ports to the VLAN you can do something like this and also use the range command to apply this to multiple ports. This selects ports 1-16.

```
Switch(config)#interface range FastEthernet 0/1-16
```

Then configure those ports to use a specific VLAN in access mode

```
Switch(config-if-range)#switchport access vlan 1
```

There is alot more to do but this hopefully gives you a high level run down.

Hope this helps you on your quest.

SleepyMan

Comment: Thanks heaps man, I will definitely try this and let you know how it goes. Once again appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Packet tracer and GNS3 for simulation is a great idea to start....9tut along with the Cisco forums can also be a good source of helpful info if you are having issues grasping a concept.

If you can afford to do it I highly recommend building a home lab setup using a pre-fab home lab which you can purchase off of Ebay or the like. Usually you get a few 2821 routers and a couple of 3560 switches to go along with them, including all of the necessary add on cards. This will give you ability to run IOS 15 and get some hands on practice. The going rate is usually about 299 but sometimes you can find one on CL.com etc for less if someone is selling theirs on the cheap.

The two biggest things, read the cert guides. Those things have some valuable info if you are just starting out. Secondly, practice...practice and more practice. In my opinion hands on practice is one of the best ways to become proficient with the material along with using the concepts in a functioning environment. CCNA was a tough go, but with effort most people of average intelligence can learn and master the material. The Cisco cert courses have been some of the most valuable sources of info around, I definitely feel like without them I would have never made the jump to admin level and ultimately engineer level positions.

Comment: Thanks for your advises Ty Smith. I will surely keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

A best way create two VLANS  in switch initially .

**Assuming two Vlans are Vlan10 & Vlan20 **

`Switch1(config)# Vlan10`
`Switch1(config)# name internet`

`Switch1(config)#Vlan 20` Switch1(config)#name LAN`

**Now assign Vlan 10 for range of switch ports from 1-16**

`Switch(config)#int gigabit range 1/1-16`

`Switch(config)#switchport mode access`

`Switch(config)#Switchport access Vlan 10`

`Switch(config)#no shutdown`

**Similarly assign Vlan 20 for remaining ports**

`Switch(config)#int gigabit range 1/17-32`

`Switch(config)#switchport mode access`

`Switch(config)#switch access vlan 20`

`Switch (config)# no shutdown`